# How to use reactive inside custom function?

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use reactive expression inside function I wrote. What I need to do is to pass some data to function (as parameter) and then return value from reactive expression. Unfortunately when I run this code then I got an error: *'data' must be a data frame or matrix*. Btw 'data' I'm passing to function is already a data frame. Is it something wrong with my code? I mean using reactive in function?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
  callModule(module, id)
}

mod_btn_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("x"))
  )
}

mod_btn_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- NS(id)
   
     output$x <- renderPrint({
       print(reactiveDf2(quakes))      
   })
     
     reactiveDf2 <- function(data){
       
       x <-  1
       r <- reactive({
    
         if (x == 2) {
           newDf <- data
         } else {
           newDf <- data[1:10,]
         }         
       }) 
      
       return(r)       
     }
  })
}


# Final app #

ui <- fluidPage(  
  tagList(
    mod_btn_ui("test"))  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  mod_btn_server("test")  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the code there is no data in text area displayed.

Comment: this code works, did you source this version of the function?

Comment: This error is from the DT package, I think. You should post the full code.

Comment: I change the code a little bit, adding variable x to make it reproducible. `quakes` is built-in R dataset so you can run the code now

Comment: Try `return(r())` in your function, it works fine.

Comment: Or `reactiveDf2(quakes)()`.